# Find_library fails using different versions of cmake

Tags: cmake

```
find_library(
    MPI_LIB
    NAMES "libmpi.so" "libmpich.so" 
    PATHS ${MPI_ROOT}/lib
    PATH_SUFFIXES "lib" "lib64"
    NO_DEFAULT_PATH
)
```

The above find_library successfully finds the mpi libraries if used with cmake/3.2 but fails if used with cmake/3.11. Is cmake not backward compatible with this function ?

Comment: It should be.  What is the directory structure and file names that works for 3.2 but fails for 3.11? An example that demonstrates the problem to see if it is reproducible would be useful.

Comment: It is on linux, the filename is "libmpi.so" and the root is found correctly. but MPI_LIB is not being assigned, This is part of a very large code and I am afraid  I can not post the enite code as of right now.

Comment: No needs to show the entire code, what we want is a [mcve] - relatively small code which demonstrates the problem and can be run at out side. "the root is **found** correctly." - What do you mean by "found"? Command `find_library` searches the files, but it doesn't report intermediate results. Or do you mean that `PATHS` option points to the directory immediately containing `libmpi.so`? Or the file is located under additional(!) `lib` subdirectory? Please, provide more details, like **exact path** to the library file, **exact value** of `PATHS` option and so on.

Comment: What about the most recent version of CMake, 3.17? Maybe it is a regression, that should be or is already fixed. What do you mean by `MPI_LIB`? Such variable does not exists within FindMPI.cmake. `MPI_LIBRARY` is deprecated. Anyway, you can check the Git history of FindMPI.cmake, maybe this sheds some light on your issue.